# Undefined property on query builder while refactoring

Tags: php, laravel

I'm refactoring some code from a controller, and I'm getting this error:

`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$total`

I don't understand why the error is popping up and I cannot figure out how to make it work. Any help is appreciated. There is a lot of code that goes into this controller, so I tried to simplify it. If what I have is hard to follow, let me know and i can adjust. Thanks!

```php
$input = Input::all();

$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$role_id = User::UserRoleData()->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->first();
$month = !empty($input['month']) ? $input['month'] : 'twentyfour';
$companies = Company::DistinctCompanies()->orderby('name')->get();

$pending = Contract::GetData()->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->where('system_status', '=', 'Pending')->where('hold', '=', '0');

if ($month == 'twentyfour') {
    if ($role_id['id'] == '5' || $role_id['id'] == '6' || $role_id['id'] == '7' || $role_id['id'] == '8') {
        if ($call_center == '52') {
            $asi_contracts = array('26', '35', '4', '42', '45', '46', '47', '49', '50', '51');
            $pending->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', 'EACP%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9466%')->where('contracts.moxy_contract_id', 'not like', '9836%')->where("sold_date", ">=", "'".$date."'")->get()->first();
        } else {
            $pending->where('contracts.call_center', '=', $call_center)->where("sold_date", ">=", "'".$date."'")->get()->first();
        }
    }
}
View::share('active_nav', 'Dashboard');
return view('dash.dash');
$pending->get()->first();
View::share('active_nav', 'Dashboard');
return view('dash.dash')->with('pending_contracts', number_format($pending->total));
```

Comment: From what I gather, `$pending` is some kind of query builder, right? Then `$pending->get()->first()` should `return` an object containing the data you want, but you're attempting to retrieve `total` from `$pending` and not the returned object which you're not even storing anywhere. Please try e.g. `$data_object = $pending->get()->first()` and then do `$data_object->total` instead.

Comment: Also check your `{` match your `}`

Answer (score 3):

The error is in the line near the end.

`$pending->get()->first();`

This return value should be assigned to something. To get the total, you could do

`$pending_total = $pending->get()->first()->total;`

and then use `$pending_total` on the last line like,

`return view('dash.dash')->with('pending_contracts', number_format($pending_total));`

and that would work fine.